# How to keep numbers on x-axis in graph

Tags: excel, excel-2011

I have recently made a bar graph in microsoft excel 2011 and want to label the bottom x-axis values as 'Optimization Level' with numbers corresponding to each bar. When I click the 'select data source' menu and then insert the word 'Optimization Level' in the Category X Axis Labels, all numbers disappear. How do I keep the numbers on the bottom of the graph? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Mac, but in Windows versions Axis Title (for Optimization Level) is distinct from Axis values.